# Truncate Text Within Specific HTML Tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, substr

This might not even be possible but I have quite a limited knowledge of PHP so I can't figure out if it is or not.

Basically I have a string `$myText` and this string outputs HTML in the following format:

```
<p>This is the main bit of text</p>
<small> This is some additional text</small>
```

My aim is to limit the number of characters displayed specifically within the `<p>` tag, for example 10 characters.

I have been playing around with PHP substr but I can only get this to work on all of the text, not just the text in the `<p>` tag.

Do you know if this is possible and if it is, do you know how to do it? Any pointers at all would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: have you considered using a javascript plugin like this one http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/ , instead?  Otherwise, can you paste some of the code you've tried in PHP? ($myText might have a lot of paragraphs. How do you know which long ones to limit?)

Comment: Hi cornelb, I will update my question to include some code. $myText will only ever have 1 paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

```
<?php
$text = '
<p>This is the main bit of text</p>
<small> This is some additional text</small>';

$pos = strpos($text,'<p>');
$pos2 = strpos($text,'</p>');

$text = '<p>' . substr($text,$pos+strlen('<p>'),10).substr($text,$pos2);

echo $text;
```

but it will work just for first pair of `<p> ... </p>`

If you need more, you can use regular expressions:

```
<?php

$text = '
<p>This is the main bit of text</p>
<small> This is some additional text</small> 

<p>

werwerwrewre

</p>';


preg_match_all('#<p>(.*)</p>#isU', $text, $matches);


foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    $text = str_replace('<p>'.$match.'</p>', '<p>'.substr($match,0,10).'</p>', $text);

}

echo $text;
```

or even

```
<?php

$text = '
<p>This is the main bit of text</p>
<small> This is some additional text</small> 

<p>

werwerwrewre

</p>';



$text = preg_replace_callback('#<p>(.*)</p>#isU', function($matches) {
 $matches[1] = '<p>'.substr($matches[1],0,10).'</p>';
 return $matches[1];
}, $text);

echo $text;
```

However in those all 3 cases, all white characters are assumed as part of the string, so if the content of `<p>...</p>` starts with 3 spaces and you want to display only 3 characters, you simple display only 3 spaces, nothing more. Of course it can be quite easily modified, but I mentioned it to notice that fact.

And one more thing, quite possible you will need to use multibyte version of functions to get the result, so for example instead of `strpos()` you should use `mb_strpos()` and set earlier utf-8 encoding using `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` to make it working

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by a quite simple way:

```
<?php

$max_length = 5;
$input = "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div><div>another very very long item</div>";
$elements_count =  preg_match_all("|(<[^>]+>)(.*)(</[^>]+>)|U",
    $input,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for($i=0; $i<$elements_count; $i++){
    echo $out[1][$i].substr($out[2][$i], 0, $max_length).$out[3][$i]."\n";  
}
```

these will work for any tag and any class or attribute within it.

ex. input:

```
<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div><div>another very very long item</div>
```

output:

```
<b>examp</b>    
<div align=left>this </div>    
<div>anoth</div>
```